# Dynamic number of rows in Laravel Blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I want a dynamic number of rows in a table like this.

```
number   name
1        Devy
```

This my Blade template.

```
<thead>
        <th>number</th>
        <th>name</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach ($aaa as $value)
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>{{$value->name}}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

How do I do that?

Comment: You can use name="myname[]"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is correct:

```
    @foreach ($collection as $index => $element)
           {{$index}} - {{$element['name']}}
   @endforeach
```

And you must use index+1 because index starts from 0.

Using raw PHP in view is not the best solution. Example:

```
<tbody>
    <?php $i=1; @foreach ($aaa as $value)?>

    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $i;?></td>
        <td><?php {{$value->name}};?></td>
    </tr>
   <?php $i++;?>
<?php @endforeach ?>
```

in your case:

```
<thead>
    <th>number</th>
    <th>name</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach ($aaa as $index => $value)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$index}}</td> // index +1 to begin from 1
            <td>{{$value}}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

Comment: unless $collection (or $aaa) has a custom index numbering like record id that might not be incremental or filtered.

Comment: For laravel 5.3+ use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30142864/dynamic-number-of-rows-in-laravel-blade/54495548#54495548), better solution.

Comment: This is not working if you sortby() your collection. The $index will display in the wrong order because it is refering to the collection items sequence before it is sorted.  The {{$loop->iteration}} works better.

Comment: correct one.. +1

Answer (score 21):

Try `$loop->iteration` variable.

`

```
<thead>
     <th>number</th>
     <th>name</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach ($aaa as $value)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$loop->iteration}}</td>
            <td>{{$value}}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

`

Comment: This must be the standard answer without any hack of +1.

Comment: This answer is straightforward and correct.

Answer (score 7):

Use a counter and increment its value in loop:

```
<thead>
        <th>number</th>
        <th>name</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <?php $i = 0 ?>
    @foreach ($aaa as $value)
    <?php $i++ ?>
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $i}}</td>
            <td>{{$value->name}}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 5):

Use $loop variable

refer this link [Loop Variable](https://mattstauffer.co/blog/the-new-loop-variable-in-laravel-5-3)

Answer (score 2):

Starting from Laravel 5.3, this has been become a lot easier. Just use the $loop object from within a given loop. You can access $loop->index or $loop->iteration. Check this answer: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/count-in-a-blade-foreach-loop-is-there-a-better-way/replies/305861

Answer (score 1):

Just take a variable before `foreach()` like `$i=1`. And increment `$i` just before `foreach()` ends. Thus you can `echo $i` in the desired `<td></td>`

Answer (score 1):

try the following:

```
<thead>
    <th>number</th>
    <th>name</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach ($aaa as $index => $value)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$index}}</td>
            <td>{{$value}}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

Comment: This answer is not correct. Because the question means something else. If there is a 'where' condition in the query then this numbering will be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can Use it like this in Blade. I hope this will help.

```
<thead>
    <th>number</th>
    <th>name</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach ($aaa as $index => $value)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$index +1}}</td>
            <td>{{$value}}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

**Note:** `{{$index +1}}` since `$index` starts from 0

Answer (score 1):

Laravel 8 -

```
<?php $serial = "1"; ?> - Before @foreach loop
<td>{{ $serial++ }}</td> - Inside @foreach loop
```