# Control DataTables columns visibility with checkboxes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, datatables

I am using [datatables](/questions/tagged/datatables) to dynamically render a table on my blade template. I have a series of checkboxes that user can check to show/hide table columns. All of this is working great.

This is what my template looks like:

**template.blade.php**

```
<table id="dataTables-report" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
</table>
```

Here is what I am using to render the table:

**scripts.js**

```
$('#dataTables-report').DataTable({
  ...
  columnDefs: [
      {
          targets: 0,
          title: 'Name',
          searchable: true,
          data: function (row, type, val, meta) {
              // return row.data;
          }
      },
      @if($report->order_date)
            {
                targets: 1,
                title: 'Order Date',
                searchable: false,
                data: function (row, type, val, meta) {
                    // return row.data;
                }
            },
       @endif
       @if($report->order_number)
            {
                targets: 2, // could be 1 if order date is not selected
                title: 'Order Number',
                searchable: false,
                data: function (row, type, val, meta) {
                    // return row.data;
                }
            },
       @endif
      ...
});
```

"Order Date" is a checkbox that a user can choose to display on the table. If it is checked, it shows that column. Otherwise it does not.
It is possible that a different column could be selected first and it could be `targets: 1`. Now if a user checks another box, `targets` needs to dynamically get set to the next number. In this case: `targets: 2`.

Each checkbox is stored as it's own column in the database, so I don't think I can do any sort of loop (hence a bunch of if statements). Otherwise, I think [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30142864/dynamic-number-of-rows-in-laravel-blade) would work.

Is there a way to dynamically generate the `targets` number right in my blade template?

Comment: Are you refreshing the page anytime you want to update the table? I feel like this would be a lot easier to manage (and would remove those if statements) if you used the ajax part of DataTables. Then you could just keep the current column count as a JS variable to be modified as columns are added/removed.

Comment: Great question - If I choose/check "Order Date" I have to click a "Save" button. The button does a full `POST` so the page refreshes.

Comment: Other than using JS and Ajax, you would have to post the target to the controller along with your other request data. Maybe a hidden field that is updated anytime a checkbox is checked/uncheck that stores a json string of what order things were checked /unchecked in. That seems a bit off to me though. I would try to use datatable's built in ajax to save the trouble.

Comment: @Damon : I have suggested my solution [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56832795/11299053). Have you tried that?

Comment: I have not yet had a chance to update my code, but I am absolutely going to give it a try. It seems much less "hacky" than what I've got. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

If you're seeking truly dynamic column visibility controlled by checkboxes (as I understood your ultimate goal), it can be done user-end entirely by few lines of jQuery.

In order to do that, you may simply

- append source object property of each column as a `value` attribute to your `<input>` nodes:
- upon `change` event, find the column that is sourced (using [`column().dataSrc()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/column().dataSrc()) method) by the object property that corresponds to clicked checkbox value and adjust that column visibility (using [`.column().visible()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/column().visible()) method accordingly:

```
$('#checkboxWrapper').on('change', '[type="checkbox"]', event => {
  let colindex = null;
  dataTable.columns().every(function(){
    if(this.dataSrc() == $(event.target).val()) colindex = this.index();
  });
  dataTable.column(colindex).visible($(event.target).prop('checked')).draw();
});
```

Complete **live demo** of that concept you may find below:

```js
//sample source data
const dataSrc = [
  {id: 1, item: 'apple', cat: 'fruit'},
  {id: 2, item: 'carrot', cat: 'vegie'},
  {id: 3, item: 'banana', cat: 'fruit'}
];

//extract all unique object keys from data source array
const checkboxes = [...new Set(dataSrc
  .map(item => Object.keys(item))
  .flat())];
//translate those into <input> nodes HTML
const checkboxesHtml = checkboxes.reduce((inputs, prop) => inputs += `<input type="checkbox" value="${prop}" checked>${prop}</input>`,'');
$('#checkboxWrapper').append(checkboxesHtml);

//initialize datatables
const dataTable = $('#example').DataTable({
  data: dataSrc,
  dom: 't',
  columns: checkboxes.map(prop => ({title: prop, data: prop}))
});

//control columns visibility with checkboxes
$('#checkboxWrapper').on('change', '[type="checkbox"]', event => {
  //grab column().index() that corresponds to checkbox value
  let colindex = null;
  dataTable.columns().every(function(){
    if(this.dataSrc() == $(event.target).val()) colindex = this.index();
  });
  //toggle selected column visibility
  dataTable.column(colindex).visible($(event.target).prop('checked')).draw();
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="application/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="application/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="checkboxWrapper"></div>
  <table id="example"></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your suggestions, here is what I came up with as a "quick" solution while I look further into your recommendations.

In my blade template, I created a global variable that I could access within my php.

```
@section('scripts')
    <script>
        $(function () {
            ...
            let columnTarget = 0;

            ...

            $('#dataTables-report').DataTable({
                ...
               columnDefs: [
               {
                   targets: columnTarget,
                   title: 'Name',
                   searchable: true,
                   data: function (row, type, val, meta) {
                       // return row.data;
               }
           },
           @if($report->order_date)
           {
               targets: ++columnTarget,
               title: 'Order Date',
               searchable: false,
               data: function (row, type, val, meta) {
                  // return row.data;
               }
           },
           @endif
           @if($report->order_number)
           {
               targets: ++columnTarget,
               title: 'Order Number',
               searchable: false,
               data: function (row, type, val, meta) {
                // return row.data;
               }
           },
           @endif
         ...
    </script>
@endsection
```

This seems to work well; correctly (dynamically) assigning the `targets` value.

Answer (score 0):

```
->addColumn('action', function ($floor) {
    $action=  
    @Can("floor-edit"){"
         <a class='btn btn-info  btn-sm' 
             href=".route("floor.edit",Crypt::encrypt($floor->id))."><i class='fa fa-edit'></i>
         </a>
         <button type='button' name='delete' id=".Crypt::encrypt($floor->id)." class='delete btn btn-danger btn-sm'><i class='fa fa-trash'></i></button>
   "};
   return $action;
})
```